# Tastypie: getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_clone'" Error

Tags: python, django, tastypie

When I try to issue a GET to my model (using `TastyPie`), I get the following traceback error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 
2141, in get_object_list
return self._meta.queryset._clone()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_clone'
```

Below is my `resources.py` file for the relevant Model.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from swtr.models import Com

class ComResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        query_set = Com.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'com'
        object_class = none
```

I'm particularly confused given that `Com.objects.all()` returns at least one record that I created and saved within the python shell. So I'm not sure why the queryset is being returned as a `NoneType`.

Comment: include the full traceback and the view that is causing this error

Comment: Are you sure it is `query_set` and not `queryset` in your `ComResource`'s Meta class?

Comment: @wencakisa Wow - you're right - it's queryset! I don't know how I missed that while pouring through the documentation... Thanks a ton for spotting that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled some fields in your `ComResource`'s `Meta` class.

Try renaming `query_set` to `queryset` and give `object_class` a value of `None`, not `none`:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from swtr.models import Com


class ComResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Com.objects.all()
        # __^
        resource_name = 'com'
        object_class = None
        # _____________^
```